# Video editing in mediocre hardware

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor, hardware

I was thinking of an idea to edit full HD videos in mediocre hardware. Firstly downscale entire video clips to a lower resolution eg. 640px. Edit and play around with these low res clips. Then let the computer repeat these on high resolution clips overnight (undisturbed).

This there such an option or is it possible using a python script ?

Comment: You should just use proxy feature (generate 25% proxies of your strips, use those for editing [by choosing them as display source], and you are done). See [the manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/strips/properties/proxy_timecode.html)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/58337/2843

Comment: @mont29 this should be an answer and no comment ;-)

Comment: @samoth done :)

Answer (score 5):

Proxy feature is designed for that purpose, make it easier to edit heavy video sequences. Generate 25% proxies of your strips, use those for editing (by choosing them as `Proxy render size` option of the `View Settings` panel), and you are done. Original files will be used automatically for final render.

See [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/properties/proxy_timecode.html) for more details.